# Remove substring from a string in python

Tags: python, string

I have got a file in python with filenames. I want to delete some lines and some substirng of the filename using python code. My file format is the above:

```
img/1.jpg
img/10.jpg
img/100.jpg 0 143 84 227
...
```

I want to delete the img/substring from all the file and the lines where the coordinates are missing. For the second task I did the following:

```
for con in content:
  if ".jpg\n" in con:
        content.remove(con)

for con in content:
    print con
```

However content didn't change.

Comment: Is ```content``` supposed to be each line in the file?

Comment: You really don't want to modify the `content` list while iterating over it with a `for` loop either.

Comment: Yes and every line is a filename for example img/1.jpg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're attempting to modify the list `content` while iterating over it. This will very quickly bite you in the knees.

Instead, in python you generate a new list:

```
>>> content = [fn for fn in content if not fn.endswith(".jpg\n")]
>>>
```

After this you can overwrite the file you read from with the contents from... `contents`. The above example assumes there is no whitespace to accomodate for in between the filename and the newline.

Answer (score 1):

The error in your current method is because you are iterating through each line *by letter*, `for l in somestring:` will go letter by letter.  Obviously, a `".jpg\n"` won't be in a single letter, so you never hit `content.remove(con)`.

I would suggest a slightly different approach:

```
with open("fileofdata.txt", 'r') as f:
    content = [line for line in f.readlines() if len(line.split()) > 1]
```

Using `len(line.split())` is more robust than `line.endswith()` because it allows for withspace between `.jpg` and `\n`.